# grep a string from a specific column

Tags: grep

My goal is to display a list of log names, from the start time column, grepping for `20161221`. I use this command:

```
$ ls -m1 /var/log/audit.raw.* | grep 20161221
/var/log/audit.raw.20161220173001EST.20161221000004EST.gz
/var/log/audit.raw.20161221000004EST.20161221083001EST.gz
/var/log/audit.raw.20161221083001EST.20161221163000EST.gz
/var/log/audit.raw.20161221163000EST.20161222000004EST.gz
```

But the first entry is from `20161220`. I know I can trim it successfully with this command instead:

```
$ ls -m1 /var/log/audit.raw.* | grep 20161221 | tail -n +2 
/var/log/audit.raw.20161221000004EST.20161221083001EST.gz
/var/log/audit.raw.20161221083001EST.20161221163000EST.gz
/var/log/audit.raw.20161221163000EST.20161222000004EST.gz
```

I wanted to see if there is a more intelligent use of grep to avoid trimming the output with `tail -n +2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do may be done using just `ls`:

```
$ ls /var/log/audit.raw.20161221*
```

Comment: ok I didnt even think of that and it is exactly what I needed.

Comment: That was embarrassing :)

Comment: @Steve Sometimes, the simplest thing is obscured by too much thinking :-) If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the
answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).